# Unable to push data from file to elastic search

Tags: logstash, elasticsearch

I am trying to read a son file data and visualize it in Kibana.The following is my stack.

read json file --> logstash --> elastic search -> Kibana (UI)

I tried the following simple configuration and it works fine till it reaches kibana.

```
input { stdin { } }
output {
elasticsearch { host => localhost }
}
```

When I tried to read the data from file and push it to elastic.I am not able to see the output .

```
input {
stdin {
type => "stdin-type"
}

file {
type => "jsonlog"

# Wildcards work, here :)
path => [ "/Users/path/logstash-1.5.0/sample.json" ]
codec => json
}
}
output {
stdout { }
elasticsearch { embedded => true }
}
```

Output : It says "logstash started".But I could not see the results in elastic nor the stdout

```
Jun 10, 2015 4:32:10 PM org.elasticsearch.node.internal.InternalNode start
INFO: [logstash-MacBook-Pro.local-12298-9782] started
Logstash startup completed
```

Software Version :

Logstash -> 1.5.0
Elasticsearch -> 1.5.2

Thanks in advance !

Comment: facing similar problem not sure how to debug :?

Comment: @atom217  Oh !  I am stuck there and could not proceed.

Comment: if you can try using  start_position => "beginning" might solve your issue. https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/plugins-inputs-file.html

Comment: @atom217 thanks for the suggestion.I tried with that too but it dosent work.

Comment: Add `sincedb_path => "/dev/null"` to the `file { }` it forces to re-read the file, even if logstash has already processed it. For the `stdout { }`, I personally use `codec => rubydebug` to format the output nicely. And then for me, your code works.